# "our important customer" vs. "important customer of ours"

Tags: double-possessives

Any difference between:

> "He is an important customer of ours"

and:

> "He is our important customer"

Comment: The first sentence would imply you have more than one important customer while the 2nd one points out that the person you're talking about is important.

Comment: In the construction ***an X of Y***, if ***Y*** is a ***pronoun*** we almost always use the possessive form *(customer of **ours**, friend of **mine**)*. But that's not always the case with other nouns, as explored by [my question about the usage on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/), where it's pointed out that plenty of people who would never say ***He's a friend of me*** are perfectly happy with ***He's a friend of the King.***

Comment: Please see the previous question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/180638/use-of-his-or-him

Comment: then what about "He is one of our important customers"? Would it be exactly the same as the "He is an important customer of ours"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's pretty different.

The first sentence means "**He is one of our important customers**". You have several important customers, and he's one of them. "**ours**" refers to "**our important customers**".

On your second sentence, you're saying you only have **one** important customer. It's technically correct but I don't think it's employed a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When someone has more than one of something, we can use *a/an + noun +*

- **of + noun + 's**: "That's a good idea." "Actually, it was an idea of John's." (one of John's ideas)
- **of + possessive pronoun**: Gerald is a cousin of mine from Devon. (one of my cousins)

So, if you say *"he is an important customer of ours"*, you mean he is **one of** your important customers. If you say "he is our important customer", there is nothing in the sentence that would imply that you have other customers. You just state the fact - that customer is important to you.